# Firebase Cloud Functions with Google Cloud Sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am facing enoent issue to connect in cloud sql.
{

> errno: -2,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '/cloudsql/Instance',
> fatal: true
> }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not formatting your instance connection string correctly.

Instead of `instance` it should be `project-name:region:instance-name`.

For example:

```
my-cool-project:us-central1:my-cool-db
```